# Is the given function intergable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

For which values of $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is the function $f: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto \frac{(x-1)}{x^a \ln(x)}$ integrable ?

I have tried with trial and error to at least get $a \neq 1$,$a \neq 2$. But this process is extremely laborious and time consuming.

I think it would be easier to apply the Dominated convergence theorem to show the integrability of the function. I think I can find a such a function $g$ if I consider functions for which $f =O(g)$ as $ x \to 0$ ( at least for one of the end points ). But then I donot know how to find such a function in general ?

I have tried $x^{-1}$,$x^{-a}$ but I am unsure if I am correct.

Comment: Do you know the exponential integral function ?

Comment: "Integrable" *where* ?

Comment: You have problems both at zero and one. I suggest you first do $\int_0^1=\int_0^{1/2}+\int_{1/2}^1$ and check each integral separately. Your could check the behavior of your function at $x=0$ and $x=1$ and (at $x=0$) compare with $\int_0^{1/2}1/x^p\,dx$ that is integrable if and only if $p<1$.